# Change MS visual studio build settings in .csproj file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

when I add a projct to my solution, in the .csproj file of it there are some lines :

```
<ItemGroup>
<Content Include="icons\add-1-icon.png" />
<Content Include="icons\divide2.png" />
<Content 
...
...
...
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
...
...
...
</ItemGroup>
```

I want to insert "Resource" tag instead of "Content" tag when I add a resource to the project, what can I do?

Comment: Change the type to resource in Visual Studio?

Comment: @DanielMann, yes, instead of <ItemGroup> <Content ... > it adds <ItemGroup> <Resource ...> to the .csproj file.(for example when I add a picture to my project then instead of <Content Include="icons\icon.png" /> it adds <Resource Include="icons\icon.png" />)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click on an item in Solution Explorer, and look in the Property Grid (F4), you will see a property named "Build Action". Change the Build Action to "Resource", and it will make it a resource.